# Performance Check for C# Method Calls

Tags: c#, reflection, system.diagnostics

i want to create a class which write a file with all Method Calls in hierarchy structure and needed Time from my Program. I have no idea how to resolve this issue. All i found is the StackTrace and StackFrame class but this not really what i need. I want to start my programm and do some action. In background my class write a file (XML for example) with following or similar structure:

```
Method1: 220ms
  Method2: 180ms
    Method3: 150ms
  Method4: 25ms
    Method5: 20ms
Method6: 110ms
```

Is there a simple way to do this? Iam actualy searching in System.Diagnostics and System.Reflection Namespace but i got no idea how to do this.

I have not written a single line of code up to this time because i need a good hint.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to do? Maybe profiling is what you need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx

Comment: @OcasoProtal Is it possible that i need VS2013 for it? Cant find the analyse menu on my VS2010 :(

Comment: Vs2010: [Ultimate and premium version contains this feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try [Mini Profiler](http://miniprofiler.com/). I usually use it to trace execution time.

Then to trace a method do this ( as mentioend in the docs) -

```
using StackExchange.Profiling;
...
var profiler = MiniProfiler.Current; // it's ok if this is null
using (profiler.Step("Set page title"))
{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
using (profiler.Step("Doing complex stuff"))
{
    using (profiler.Step("Step A"))
    { // something more interesting here
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    using (profiler.Step("Step B"))
    { // and here
        Thread.Sleep(250);
    }
}
```

It has a nice interface to show you how much time each step needed for web -

[image]

For windows and console based application use the windows extension mentioned here -

http://nootn.github.io/MiniProfiler.Windows/

and the process is mentioned here -

http://www.nootn.com.au/2012/07/performance-profiling-console-or-winwpf.html#.U8i-TDS1bcg

Comment: Your post feels like comment... Make sure to add actual answer how to implement it yourself.